# Per-test coverage in Go

Tags: go

I am building a Go provider for [Pruner](https://github.com/pruner/cli) (a CLI that runs only the tests that ran through the lines you changed, saving you time).

For that, I need to be able to see per-test coverage. Not just a full coverage report after all tests have run, but I need a way to know *which tests ran through what line*.

Is that possible in Go?

I tried using `-func`, but it just gives me the method names of the original code, not the test code. In other words, I can't know what code each individual test runs through.

Comment: I don't know if there's a native Go way to see that data. If third-party tools are allowed, Goland actually shows that information(when tests are run with Coverage), what lines are covered or not by the tests, but I found no information on their website on how they do it, so it might be proprietary code.

Answer (score 2):

> I need a way to know which tests ran through what line.
>
> Is that possible in Go?

It's not supported by the tools. But you can do it. It's just very inefficient.

The way to do this is to run:

```sh
go test -cover -run=TheName/OfSome/SpecificTest
```

Then run this *for each test* in your suite.

Naturally, this will make your tests much more cumersome to manage, and incredibly slow.

So I would consider whether this is truly a requrement for your use case.

Go is optimized, from the ground-up, to compile quickly.  If you have a Go project so long, that running all the tests is too slow, you may want to consider other alternatives.  Some suggestions:

1. Run more tests [in parallel](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Parallel), so the total runtime is reduced.
2. Take advantage of [Short mode](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Short), and only run short tests by default, saving long-running tests for special cases.
3. If you really need to run only a subset of tests, do it on a per-package basis, not on a per-test basis.

Comment: What about integration tests that need to spawn up a whole database, or a whole setup etc? Those are just inherently slow. But perhaps those aren't found much in the Go community either, or?

Comment: And also, do you have any idea of how GoLand does this with high performance?